# How to find an element that is present on "Inspect" but not present on page source with Selenium? C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am creating a bot that will repeat actions on some website. But I'm stuck on one place where I need to press a button that is present on the page and I can get it's XPath from "Inspect" window, but

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("XPath"))
```

gives an exception. I also tried to use `WebDriverWait` and search for a frames and iframes on the page, but none of these succeed. I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you share HTML or page URL ? We need to see your code as well as errorStack trace if there's any

Comment: @cruisepandey are you OK? I did not see you here today until this moment and started to worry about you :)

Comment: @Prophet :  yeah I am all okay, pretty much busy Friday I would say. Nice to see you are taking care of the things here.

Comment: Good! I'll be out of here for a day or more, please be here for that time :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty obvious. This page was opened in a new tab, but selenium was trying to find element on first tab despite that another tab was active.